# Can we change the iOS app for upgrade?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

We have a client who already has an app (let's say A) in the app store. The client wants to use our app(let's say B) in the app store now. He does not want the users who are already using the present app (A) to go and install our app separately (B). What he wants is that users get an update message with his app(A). If the user agrees then our app (B) can replace the old one at the user's end.

Can the above scenario be handled in the present App store?

If yes, how should I start?

Any references or any documents would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: you have use the exists `Application Bundle ID` and you can replace the old one, but if the new application is totally different from the old one, the Apple might reject the upgrade.

Comment: What’s the rationale for this request? It’s not that hard to simply redirect users from the old app to the App Store page for the new one, or do what holex suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't switch app A with bundle ID com.foo (for example) for app B with bundle ID com.baz.
You can only update an app to a new version with the same bundle ID.

You *can* change the icon, title and description in an update. But I suspect Apple aren't going to like you switching app A for an entirely different app B in an update. I'd expect them to reject this.

There's no mechanism other than doing a standard App Store update to app A for what you want to do. E.g. you can't handle the 'get an update message and agree' part yourself.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible, save perhaps if Apple employees would help you with it (but I doubt they would - you could try [calling Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php/) though). The bundle identifier is linked to a developer account and an app could only be replaced if the bundle identifier somehow could be transferred to your companies developer account.